# Issues Loading Images in Flet App When Started with a Specific Port

Tags: python, flet

I'm developing a web application using the Flet framework, and I've encountered an issue where images are not being loaded when the app is started with a specific port. The images load perfectly when I start the app without specifying a port (using the default settings), but when I launch the app with a specified port (e.g., port=5081), the images fail to load.`

```
import flet as ft
import os

def main(page: ft.Page):
    img_path = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), '1001.jpg')
    xImg = ft.Image(src=img_path, width=250, height=250, fit=ft.ImageFit.CONTAIN)
    page.add(xImg)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    ft.app(target=main, port=5081)
```

it works when i start ft.app(target=main)

Comment: The error cannot be reproduced in Windows 10.